# POST request not being sent in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, post, swift3

I would just like to ask. Why is my POST request below not being sent? The code seems perfectly sound, and Xcode shows no errors. I am using Swift 3. Could you please help me? Thanks! My code is below, my post URL is [here](https://picapacas.herokuapp.com/applogin). Thanks again!

```
@IBAction func onClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let username = Username.text
    let password = Password.text

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["username": username, "password": password] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    do {
        try request.httpBody = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    request.addValue("application/JSON", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    URLSession.shared.getAllTasks { (openTasks: [URLSessionTask]) in
        NSLog("open tasks: \(openTasks)")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)`. Also, don't use `NSMutableRequest`, but use the native Swift version, `URLRequest`.

```
@IBAction func onClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let username = Username.text
    let password = Password.text

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let params = ["username": username, "password": password] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    do {
        try request.httpBody = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    request.addValue("application/JSON", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data,response, error in
        if let existingError = error {
            //handle error
        }
        //handle response and/or data
    }).resume()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
  // do stuff with response, data & error here
  print(error)
  print(response)
})
task.resume()
```

[Get more info here](https://grokswift.com/updating-nsurlsession-to-swift-3-0/)